# I am demanding the death penalty for the defendant

Tags: present-continuous

A situation in the courtroom. The prosecutor is delivering his final speech. Which sentence is correct?

*1. I am demanding the death penalty for the defendant.*

*2. I demand the death penalty for the defendant*.

Is it possible to use the continuous form of the verb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The continuous could be used, when explaining the demand, say.

> Prosecution is demanding the death penalty because ....
>
> We are seeking the death penalty because ...

The first person pronoun is unlikely.

Comment: Thank you. "The first person pronoun is unlikely". Do you mean the practise  and the rules in law courts in the US?

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical about the first-person, but it is not likely to be used in your particular context, "The prosecutor is delivering his final speech".  Normally the prosecution presents itself as The Voice of The State.